# How to modify the width of characters in vscode terminal？

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have configured the font, it can be displayed normally in iTerm2, but the characters are missing on both sides in VSCode, the effect looks very bad.

I think it's a terminal character width problem, how to modify the character width in VSCode terminal, I hope someone can tell me, I would be very grateful.

[font-family](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbjNx.png)

[iTerm2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16um2.png)

[VSCode Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lEWD.png)